# Get columns of one of two entities ... use last and groupby?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following EF entities:

```
public class Evaluation {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get, set; }
  public String Interview { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}

public class Student {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Evaluation Evaluation { get; set; }
}

public class Exam {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 Note { get; set; }
  public Int32? Factor { get; set; }
  public virtual Evaluation Evaluation { get; set; }
}

public class Test {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 Note { get; set; }
  public Int32? Factor { get; set; }
  public virtual Evaluation Evaluation { get; set; }
}
```

A few observations:

1. An evaluation can have one Exam, one Test or none.
2. An Exam or Test has a note but can have or not a Factor.

What I am looking for is:

For each student find the last Exam OR Test that has both Note AND Factor.

Then get this list of Notes / Factors and multiply both: Result = Note * Factor

I was trying the following:

```
context.Evaluations
  .Where(x => x.Exam != null || x.Test != null)
  .GroupBy(x => x.Student)
```

After this I am not sure how to get the last Exam OR Test that has both Note and Factor to use and calculate the Result.

How can I do this?

Comment: just a silly suggestion, maybe you can create an abstract class for both to inherit called TestOrExam and then add another property which is both concatenated? 
It would look like public virtual ICollection<TestOrExam> TestsOrExams { get { return Tests.Cast<TestOrExam>().Concat(Exams); };}

Comment: Test and Exam are very similar in my example but in my real code they are not ... I posted this way just to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

You said that an Evaluation can have 1 or 0 Exams but from the code a I understand that it can have many (Also ,other things don't add up but it's just because these are sample classes).

```
public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
```

If you give a better sample of your classes we may find a way to get the result you want using 1 LINQ query.
In any case you can accomplish what you want in a few statements.

If your problem is how to combine Exams and Tests you can use something similar to the following pseudocode

```
public class UserQuiz {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 Note { get; set; }
  public Int32? Factor { get; set; }
  public Evaluation Evaluation { get; set; }
}

List<UserQuiz> examsAndTest=new List<UserQuiz>();
examsAndTest.AddRange(userExams.Select(e=>new UserQuiz(){ Id= e.Id /* copy the other properties here */}).ToList());
examsAndTest.AddRange(userTests.Select(e=>new UserQuiz(){ Id= e.Id /* copy the other properties here */}).ToList());

UserQuiz latestRecord=  examsAndTest.OrderByDescending(e=>e.Evaluation.Created).FirstOrDefault();
```